# Effrayant ou effroyable

Tags: vocabulaire

Les deux mots me semblent exprimer la peur, et aussi avoir la même racine, mais je ne peux pas trouver la difference entre eux. Selon WordReference.com, « effroyable » est utilisé pour décrire les crimes violents en particulier, mais c'est tout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to some search, please find some parts of answer. It seems there is a scale difference between the two words. Note that according to "[l'Encyclopédie, 1re éd.
1751 (Tome 5, p. 412).](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/L%E2%80%99Encyclop%C3%A9die/1re_%C3%A9dition/EFFRAYANT,_EFFROYABLE,_TERRIBLE)" the point is about the subject which inspire fear or horror. The feeling is different.

From "[Français notre belle langue](https://www.achyra.org/francais/viewtopic.php?t=2354)" forum we can read :

> La réponse de Littré devrait vous satisfaire, car elle confirme ce que vous dites :
>    EFFRAYANT, EFFROYABLE. Ces deux mots ont même origine, puisque effrayer et effroyer sont deux formes d'un même mot ; il n'y a donc de différence que dans la finale : effrayant est le participe présent d'effrayer ; effroyable est l'adjectif verbal d'effroyer. La nuance est que effrayant est strictement limité à la crainte, tandis que à effroyable se joint l'idée accessoire d'horrible.
>
> Voyons l'Académie :
>   EFFRAYANT, -ANTE adj. XVIe siècle. Participe présent d'effrayer.
>   Qui provoque une peur violente ; qui effraie. Un spectacle effrayant. Une figure effrayante. Un songe effrayant. Par exag. Fam. Il a un travail effrayant. Il fait une chaleur effrayante !
>   EFFROYABLE adj. XIVe siècle, au sens de « d'une laideur repoussante ». Dérivé d'effroi.
>   Qui cause de l'effroi. Un spectacle, une vision effroyable. Il proférait des menaces effroyables. Un accident effroyable. Par exag. Il s'est lancé dans d'effroyables dépenses. Il faisait un temps effroyable.
>   En conclusion, il semble qu'il y ait une différence de degré de signification, ce qui est effrayant cause une certaine crainte (au sens figuré de l'inquiétude par son ampleur), l'effroyable provoque une terreur, une peur violente par une grande intensité dramatique.

The TLFI dictionnary suggests the same differences about "effroi" roots.
[effrayant](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/effrayant)
[effroyable](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/effroyable)

Comment: Réponse très intéressante et que je vote, Amaury, mais attention à la frappe: vous avez écrit CNTRL au lieu de CNRTL.

Comment: @BBBreiz Ni l'un, ni l'autre. Il s'agit du TLFi.

Comment: CNRTL est désormais corrigé.

Answer (score 3):

*Le Grand Robert de la langue française* distingue ces termes de cette façon :

> [Effrayant] “Qui inspire ou peut inspirer de la frayeur, de l'effroi.”
>
> [Effroyable] “Qui remplit d'effroi, de terreur.”

Introduisant donc une nuance logique, modale : l'effroyable suscite nécessairement l'effroi, tandis que l'effrayant est susceptible de le susciter.

Ceci expliquant cela, *Le Grand Robert historique de la langue française* précise quant à “effroyable” (XV-XVIe s.) qu'il s'agit “d'un doublet plus fort de *effrayant* [1539], d'un usage soutenu”.

Comment: Il serait intéressant que vous listiez les synonymes et contraires donnés par le Petit Robert :-)

Comment: Il s'agit du Grand Robert, et précisément de deux ouvrages différents : *Le Grand Robert de la langue française* (GRLF) et Le *Grand Robert* historique *de la langue française*. Le GRLF ne propose pas de synonymes pour ces termes, seulement des antonymes, les voici : « Effroyable. : Admirable, attirant, charmant, délicieux, magnifique, ravissant, superbe. » | « Effrayant : Attirant, rassurant, séduisant. — Infime, ridicule. »

Comment: L'ouvrage le plus proche éditorialement, par ailleurs excellent (et en outre couronné par l'Académie) est celui d'Henri Bertaud du Chazaud, auteur aux éditions Dictionnaires du Robert, en 1989, du *Dictionnaire des synonymes* (coll. « Les usuels du Robert »). Il ne donne qu’une seule liste de synonymes pour ces deux termes, classée à *Effrayant*. Reste le Dictionnaire électronique des synonymes, du Crisco, qui possède une approche cependant plus linguistique et moins littéraire (https://crisco2.unicaen.fr/des/synonymes/effroyable)